# Query Oracle SQL - Subtrair horas

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, query, oracle

Olá,
Sou iniciante em SQL e estou com uma dúvida mortal. 
Essa consulta é para analisar um log de execução em uma base da minha empresa. O problema é que o time zone do SO está +0.00 o que cria registros incorretos no meu log (não é possível fazer essa alteração, então já descartei a possibilidade).
Preciso subtrair 3 horas de um campo Timestamp e não faço a mínima ideia de como executar isso.
Também realizo um Substring para coletar a data, hora inicial e hora fim da execução. Talvez seria uma solução diminuir as 3 horas diretamente dessa substring, mas não sei como posso executar isso. Também precisaria fazer o tratamento de horas por exemplo uma execução a uma hora da manhã no log ao subtrair deve constar 22 horas.
Alguém poderia me auxiliar?

```
  SELECT DISTINCT
SUBSTR(R.RUNSTARTTIMESTAMP,10, 2) "HORA START",
SUBSTR(R.RUNSTARTTIMESTAMP,13,2) "MINUTO START",
SUBSTR(R.RUNENDTIMESTAMP,10, 2) "HORA END",
SUBSTR(R.RUNENDTIMESTAMP,13,2) "MINUTO END",
SUBSTR(R.RUNSTARTTIMESTAMP,1,8) "data",
SUBSTR(R.RUNSTARTTIMESTAMP,9, 9) "STARTTIME",
SUBSTR(R.RUNENDTIMESTAMP,9, 9) "ENDTIME",
R.RUNSTARTTIMESTAMP,
R.RUNENDTIMESTAMP,
R.ELAPSEDRUNSECS


FROM
DSODB.JobExec J,
DSODB.JobRun R,
DSODB.JobRunLog L,
DSODB.LogTypeRef T


WHERE J.ProjectName = 'MDM_PRD'

AND J.JobName = 'Sq_Ctr_MdmPes_BipPct'
AND R.JOBID = J.JOBID
AND L.RUNID = R.RUNID
AND L.LogType = T.LogTypeCode

AND  r.runstarttimestamp >= to_timestamp('06-08-2018 00:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
ORDER BY r.runstarttimestamp
ASC;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar *interval* para fazer isso, seja assim:

```
select R.RUNSTARTTIMESTAMP - numtodsinterval(3,'hour') from DSODB.JobRun R
```

ou assim:

```
select R.RUNSTARTTIMESTAMP - interval '3' hour from DSODB.JobRun R
```

Veja aqui um exemplo funcionando: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5e0e9/8

Comment: Você é o cara! Muito obrigado, resolveu o meu problema